# How to create a favorite on twitter with Codeigniter and Haughin library?

Tags: codeigniter, twitter

I'm trying to use the Haughin library to create a favorite on Twitter. I'm able to login with oauth, get my info, update my status, but the favorite call won't work. I think it's a little outdated for that function, any body made it work?

Here's the library :
http://www.haughin.com/code/twitter/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->twitter->call('favorites/create', array('id' => 1234));
```

This call is not listed in the main "docs".

Comment: it doesn't work here. the thing is that the call should be api.twitter.com/favorites/create/id.json . 
I modified the twitter class a little for it to work. I'll post the answer soon. Thanks :)